# How can I get the email id of the clicked span element which is hidden property in css

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

On click on the heart icon, how can I get the email id of the span element ( which has the display property hidden in css ) in react hooks ?

codesandbox link:
https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-khorana-ezdxo?file=/src/App.js:0-3074

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import Axios from "axios";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { Heart as HeartIcon } from "react-feather";
import "animate.css";

const moment = require("moment");

const data1 = [
  { id: 1, name: "Son", email: "sn@test.com", reason: "testing" },
  { id: 2, name: "Man", email: "mn@test.com", reason: "progress" },
  { id: 3, name: "Man", email: "op@test.com", reason: "help" }
];

const NominationView = (props) => {
  const [nominationView, setNominationView] = useState([]);
  const [likes, setLikes] = useState("");
  const isMounted = useRef(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    isMounted.current = true;
    return () => (isMounted.current = false);
  }, []);
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        // const res = await Axios.get(
        //   "http://localhost:8000/service/nominations"
        // );
        if (isMounted.current) {
          setNominationView(data1);
        }
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  const saveLikes = (email) => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const userEmail = localStorage.getItem("loginEmail");
      try {
        const res = await Axios.put(
          "http://localhost:8000/service/nominationviewsavelikes",
          { params: { userEmail, email } }
        );
        if (isMounted.current) {
          console.log("Like status :" + res.data);
        }
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
    };
    fetchData();
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="leftNavItem"></div>
      <h2>Nomination View</h2>
      {!nominationView.length && (
        <div className="dashboarddata">
          Sorry, No nominations data to display..!
        </div>
      )}
      <div className="row">
        {nominationView.map((item, i) => (
          <div
            key={item}
            className={`nominationRecord animate__animated animate__fadeInUp animate__delay-${i}s`}
          >
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/50" />
            <span key={item.nomineeFirstName} className="datarecord">
              {item.nomineeFirstName}
            </span>
            <span key={item.nomineeLastName} className="datarecord">
              {item.nomineeLastName}
            </span>
            <span key={item.nomineeemail} className="emailhide">
              {item.nomineeemail}
            </span>
            <span key={item.reason} className="datarecord">
              {item.reason.length <= 20
                ? item.reason
                : `${item.reason.substr(0, 20)}...`}
            </span>
            <span className="datarecord" key={item.createdAt}>
              {moment(item.createdAt).format("DD-MMM-YYYY")}
            </span>
            <span className="likeButton" onClick={saveLikes}>
              <HeartIcon />
            </span>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default NominationView;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use arrow function and pass the email as param:

```
<span className="likeButton" onClick={() => saveLikes(item.nomineeemail)}>
  <HeartIcon />
</span>
```

Comment: Will it get the email of the clicked item ?

Comment: Last time, when I tried it giving all of the emails ...

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
            <span
              className="likeButton"
              onClick={() => saveLikes(item.email)}
            >
              <HeartIcon />
            </span>
```